# takeOrdered key error with Pyspark in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm getting an error with the takeOrdered function in PySpark using Python 3.4.2 and Spark 1.4.1, which is supposed to support Python 3.

```
sc.parallelize([("a", 10), ("c", 5), ("b", 7)]).takeOrdered(3, key=lambda (k,v): -v)

File "<stdin>", line 1
sc.parallelize([("a", 10), ("c", 5), ("b", 7)]).takeOrdered(3, key=lambda (k,v): -v)
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This error only occurs when I use Python 3. It works perfectly fine in Python 2.7.

Also, as a comparison, this line of code works perfectly fine in Python 3:

```
sc.parallelize([("a", 10), ("c", 5), ("b", 7)]).takeOrdered(3, key=lambda (k,v): -v)
```

Is anybody getting the same error? Or am I missing something?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is your lamba function that is causing the error.

This is because you are using Python 3. Tuple parameter unpacking was removed in python 3. See Docs [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)

You can manually unpack the tuple:

```
sc.parallelize([("a", 10), ("c", 5), ("b", 7)]).takeOrdered(3, key=lambda kv: -kv[1])
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Followup: In your first example code, how would you unpack the tuple first before passing it to lambda in the same line?